# Initializer element is not constant for declaring time function globally

Tags: c, global-variables, time.h

I have my C program with time function declared globally as follows:

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
time(&rawtime);
void file_name()
{
   sprintf(buffer,"data/log_%d.%d_%d:%d:%d",tm->tm_mon+1,tm->tm_mday,tm->tm_hour,tm->tm_min,tm->tm_sec);
   char *p = buffer;
   for(;*p;++p)
  {
     if(*p == ' ')
     *p = '_';
  }
  printf("%s",buffer);
  }
}

void create_file()
{
  file_name();
  fptr = fopen(buffer,"w"); 
}

void read_data();
{
.
.
.
.

sprintf(buffer1,"_%d:%d:%d",tm->tm_hour,tm->tm_min,tm_sec);
fprintf(fptr,"%d.%d_%d:%d:%d,%d",tm->tm_mon+1,tm->tm_mday,tm->tm_hour,tm->tm_min,tm->tm_sec);
close_file();

}


int main()
    {



       read_data();

       .
       .


       return 0;
    }
```

Since I want to use `tm` in two more functions like one is filename(); and similarly another function called read_data(); in the program for printing the month, date and etc. I want to declare these globally. But when I compile the program, it gives an error called initializer element is not constant at `time_t t = time(NULL);` and `struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);` Can anyone help me in this thanks in advance.

Comment: `time_t t; int main(void) { t = time(NULL); }`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This is not a valid C program.

Comment: Still not a mcve and still not valid C. Please check your beginner's textbook for the language basics. Also read [ask] and state why you think you need to do it like this.

Comment: The C standard says *"All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration
shall be constant expressions or string literals."* You try to initialize using function calls, which is not one of the two options. So can't do.

Comment: May I know how can I initialize them in main function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code:

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
```

is not valid. You cannot call a function when initializing a global variable in C. The initializer element (ex. in `time(NULL)` for `t`) is not constant (compiler does not know it's value when compiling, ei. for `time(NULL)` the compiler does not know what time it is when the program is run, when the compiler is compiling the program).
Also you cannot call do a global function call, you must be in some function to call anything, the code:

```
 time(&rawtime);
```

is also not valid.

You can declare these variables as global variables and initialize them in main(). All global variables that don't have any initialization are initialized with 0 or NULL. Example:

```
time_t t;
struct tm *tm;
...
int main() { 
   // first things first - initialize global variables to a known state
   t = time(NULL;
   tm = localtime(&t);
   time(&rawtime);
   // other things to do
   ...
   read_data();
   ...
}
```