# How could I use `kallsyms_lookup_name` function to fix `unknown character` error when loading Linux kernel module?

Tags: hook, system-calls, kernel-module

I'm trying to complete a hooking sample attachment in a program for my uni assignment. The task requires to get a system call `sys_rt_sigaction` hooked when initiating a loadable module in Linux kernel (I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, kernel version is 5.0.0-23-generic). So, the case I'm struggling originates from an error `could not insert module <module name>: Unknown symbol in module` once I started `sudo insmod <my module name>.ko`. 
After some googling, I see clear this problem arises due to missing `sys_call_table` export to run inserting as smoothly as well. Following [this post](https://jm33.me/hook-system-calls-in-linux-5x.html), I want to cope that invoking `kallsyms_lookup_name` call before kicking off `init` procedure.
There is `.c`-file which provides with definitions of operations accessible by module (file name is `buffer.c`):

```
#define __KERNEL__
#define MODULE

#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/kallsyms.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>

void * sys_call_table = (void *) kallsyms_lookup_name("sys_call_table");// some wrongness here, but what exactly? 

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

int (*real_rt_sigaction)(const char * path); // true syscall prototype 
static int __init buffer_init_module(void);
static void __exit buffer_exit_module(void);
static int device_open(struct inode *, struct file *); // driver file opening
static int device_release(struct inode *, struct file *); // return of system resource control
static ssize_t device_read(struct file *, char *, size_t, loff_t *); // reading from driver file
static ssize_t device_write(struct file *, const char *, size_t, loff_t *); // writing into driver file

#define DEVICE_NAME "buffer"
#define BUF_LEN 80

// to be called instead  
int alter_rt_sigaction(int signum, const struct sigaction *act,
                       struct sigaction *oldact, size_t sigsetsize) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Syscall function hooked - you've lost control of your experience");
    return 0;
}


static int Major;
static int Device_Open = 0;
static int total_open = 1;

static char Buf[BUF_LEN + 1] = "Buffer is empty, add some input\n";
static char *Msg_ptr;
static int Buf_Char = 50;
static int Bytes_Read = 0;

static struct file_operations fops = {
        .read = device_read,
        .write = device_write,
        .open = device_open,
        .release = device_release
};

static int __init buffer_init_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO
    "Device initializing in progress...");
    Major = register_chrdev(0, DEVICE_NAME, &fops);
    if(Major < 0) {
        printk("Major number hasn't been assigned - Driver registration failed\n");
        return Major;
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "Registration success - device major number: %d\n", Major);
    real_rt_sigaction=sys_call_table[__NR_rt_sigaction]; 
    sys_call_table[__NR_rt_sigaction]=alter_rt_sigaction; // hooking implementation 
    return 0;
}

static void __exit buffer_exit_module(void)
{
    unregister_chrdev(Major, DEVICE_NAME);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Outside the module - exit successfully completed\n");
    sys_call_table[__NR_rt_sigaction]=real_rt_sigaction; // original call reset
}

static int device_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    if(Device_Open)
        return -EBUSY;
    Device_Open++;
    printk(KERN_INFO "Device file has been accessed %d time(s)\n", total_open++);
    Msg_ptr = Buf;
    try_module_get(THIS_MODULE);
    Bytes_Read = 0;

    return 0;
}

static int device_release(struct inode * node, struct file * filep)
{
    Device_Open--;
    module_put(THIS_MODULE);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Device file gets close\n");
    return 0;
}

static ssize_t device_read(struct file * filep, char * buffer, size_t len, loff_t * offset)
{
    int got_read = Bytes_Read;

    if(Bytes_Read >= Buf_Char)
        return 0;

    while(len && (Bytes_Read < Buf_Char)) {
        put_user(Msg_ptr[Bytes_Read], buffer+Bytes_Read);
        len--;
        Bytes_Read++;
    }
    return Bytes_Read-got_read;
}

static ssize_t device_write(struct file * filep, const char * buffer, size_t len, loff_t * offset)
{
    Buf_Char = 0;
    if(Buf_Char >= BUF_LEN) {
        return 0;
    }

    while(len && (Buf_Char < BUF_LEN))
    {
        get_user(Msg_ptr[Buf_Char], buffer+Buf_Char);
        len--;
        Buf_Char++;
    }

    return Buf_Char;
}

module_init(buffer_init_module);
module_exit(buffer_exit_module);
```

Additively, there is code in `Makefile`:

```
obj-m += buffer.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

The painful moment here is an error message `initializer element is not constant` whenever I was trying to build module via `sudo make` in my project folder. As I follow the beginner's tutorials and need for some basic insight, it might be highly appreciable to see any help with solution or even some ideas how to handle the same problem more effectively, indeed.

Comment: When initialize global variables, you may NOT call functions. But you may call functions inside other functions. E.g. inside `buffer_init_module` which is called automatically when the module is loaded. I would suggest to learn more about C programming in user space before programming kernel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initializer element is not constant for declaring time function globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731102/initializer-element-is-not-constant-for-declaring-time-function-globally)